# How to setEnabled(false) all the sap.m.Input simultaneously in sapui5 without using jquery

Tags: sapui5, sa

I am using this code but it is not giving me the result

```
sap.m.Input.prototype.onAfterRendering = function(e){
this.setEnabled(false);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: Setting enabled for every instance of your input control in onAfterRendering**

```
var oInput = sap.m.Input(...);
oInput.addEventDelegate({
    onAfterRendering : function () {
        this.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

**Option 2 : Using a view model**

```
//in controller:
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    enabled : false
});
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "view");

//...
var oInput1 = sap.m.Input({
    enabled : "{view>/enabled}"
});
var oInput2 = sap.m.Input({
    enabled : "{view>/enabled}"
});

//...
// in the controller changing the model once will affect all the input controls
this.getView().getModel("view").setProperty("/enabled", true);
```